# illegal interface identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am very new to iOS development. I have a very little background to it. I have seen a tutorial [HERE](http://hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-How-To-Display-SQLite-Data-in-a-UITableView#), I am following it but somehow I am encountering an error and I don't know why.

here is my code: this is my "AuthorVC" in my tutorials

header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ServicesMani : UITableViewController{

    NSMutableArray *theservices;
    sqlite3 *db;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *theservices;

-(NSMutableArray *) servicelist;

@end
```

and here is the implementation:

```
@implementation ServicesMani
@synthesize theservices;
```

the synthesize is the error.

Comment: What exactly is the error? And without looking you can tell it is an old tutorial as you don't need to use synthesize any more.

Comment: it says "illegal interface identifier"

Comment: Do you `#import "ServicesMani.h"` in `ServicesMani.m`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no need to use that statement here. Remove this statement from your .m(implementation) file and that will do it.

```
@synthesize theservices;
```

Remove this. Only properties that are declared in the .h files have to be synthesised. And that too is optional. You need to remove this and just directly use `theservices` variable in your .m file

Answer (score 1):

Remove `NSMutableArray *theservices;` between `{` and `}` in the `@interface` section:

```
@interface ServicesMani : UITableViewController{
    sqlite3 *db;
}
```

The compiler will automatically create a backing instance variable for `@property theservices`.